Is a way to debug angular aot compiler?
Windows 11, Angular branch 17.3.x. I build angular from official repository. It is ok. Then I try to debug angular aot compiler (not application). I follow instructions https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/docs/DEVELOPER.md#testing-changes-against-a-local-libraryproject
but only @angular/cli debug available. Is a way to debug files in @angular/compiler? This is a visualization of instructions:

I want to debug angular compiler (template parser).
I try search info in the google but it think I want to debug angular applications. This is not. Also I try to search issues in the angular repo and find nothing. I believe developers do debug. )

you can run node --inspect path/to/command/ng build, connect to that process and debug it. but why would you do that? can you try to describe what you want to achieve so SO community would be able to help you with that? compiler is a pretty complex thing and in most cases you just care about output

Hi @Andrei. Thank you for your advice! I can see @angular/compiler now and set breakpoints but only in JS version. I do not understand a trick - if I debug/attach with Chrome DevTools I do not see @angular/compiler. If I debug/attach vscode then vscode can see breakpoints in @angular/compiler and catch them.
https://i.sstatic.net/NXgHL.png
Is a way to debug a TypeScript version of angular? (There are .maps for angular compiler code: https://i.sstatic.net/YvYvy.png
